# Store and recall a variable in a text file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

How would i store the variable x on a specific line (the first)in a text file and recover it as the program opens.

Also how would i store data in a text file on a specific line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the `open()` built-in.

```
#To write to a file:
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Data!")

#To read from a file:
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Next time, you should check for duplicates:

[easy save/load of data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450144/easy-save-load-of-data-in-python), [Writing a Top Score to a data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904676/writing-a-top-score-to-a-data-file).